# Erase string a part of string in shell script

Tags: linux, string, shell

I need to delete a part of a string via shell script.

> E.g: I have this: VERBOSE [61622] [C-0000051f] And I want this:
>   C-0000051f

Without the brackets in the last portion
How can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check the awk solution

```
> data="VERBOSE [61622] [C-0000051f] "
> awk -F"[" ' { print $NF } ' <<< $data | awk -F"]" ' { print $1 } '
C-0000051f
>
```

**EDIT1:**

More compact version

```
> data="VERBOSE [61622] [C-0000051f] "
>  awk -F"[[]|]"  ' { print $4   } ' <<< $data
C-0000051f
>
```

Comment: Very close. If you make FS a regex containing both square brackets, you can do it with a single awk

Comment: That is because of the special meaning of square brackets. Try to escape them

Comment: that too didn't work.. awk: warning: escape sequence `\[' treated as plain `['

Comment: try any of the following : `[][]` or  `]|[`. Have a look here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html

Comment: it worked with  awk -F"[[]|]"  ' { print $4   } ' <<< $data

Comment: @kvantour.. this also worked.. awk -F"[[]|[]]"  ' { print $4   } ' <<< $data

Comment: Try `awk -F "[][]" '{print $(NF-1)}'`

Answer (score 0):

As I notice from you answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635361/8344060), you want to extract some information from a file and then perform a set of actions on that extracted line. The entire line you provided there, could be reduced to the following:

```
NUMTEL="$1"
IDCALL=$(awk -F "[][]" -v string="$NUMTEL" '/VERBOSE/ && ($0 ~ string){print $(NF-1);exit}' /var/log/asterisk/full)
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to do what I needed with the following script.

## !/bin/bash

NUMTEL=$1

IDCALL=`/usr/bin/grep "VERBOSE" /var/log/asterisk/full | /usr/bin/grep "$NUMTEL" | /usr/bin/head -n1 | /usr/bin/awk '{print $4}' | /usr/bin/cut -d] -f2 | /usr/bin/sed -e 's/\[//g'`

echo $IDCALL

Thank you